# All images in one single row, or all images below each other

Tags: html, css, layout

I want to have three images on a row, if the total width of these three images doesn't fit the browser window then all three images should be below each other. So it's "all or nothing", there should never be only two images beside each other and one below (this happens then you gradually decrease browser window width using `float:left;` on all three images)

All this should be centered in the browser window, no matter the size of the window.

I know limited CSS and HTML but am using the following code to get current data centered in the window:

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

html, body {
  height: 100%; 
}

table {
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <table width="280" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
          <td>
            "images and text"
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table> 
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Do the images have a fixed total width?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use bootstrap to achieve that. Click on the Full page button and change the screen size.

```css
@media (min-width:768px) {
 
 .inline-block-row .col-sm-4 {
     display: inline-block;
        float:none;
 }
}
```

```html
<body>
  
<div class="container-fluid">
   <h1>Inline Block Grid</h1>
   <div class="row inline-block-row">
      <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3">
          <div class="well"><img class="thumbnail img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/200x200"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3">
         <div class="well"><img class="thumbnail img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/200x200"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3">
         <div class="well"><img class="thumbnail img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/200x200"></div>
      </div>
     
   </div>
</div>  

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use media queries (simple +pure css), but you need to set a breakpoint (unflexible):

```
img{display:inline;}
//replace 1024 with width of all three images
@media (max-width:1024px){
    img{display:inline-block;}
}
```

Or you could use js (flexible+complicated):

```
<script>
body.onresize=function(){
    var width=0;
    images=document.getElementsByTagName("image");
   for(image in images){
   width=width+image.width;
   }
   if(width>window.innerWidth){
      document.all.img.style.display="inline-block";
  }
  }
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use pure CSS only to solve that problem, we'll use CSS media query. I'll try to explain the solution with help of an example. For that, first you should have with you the width of each image.

For example, let's say width of one image you want is `200px`, then also you'd like to have some space as margin between images too, so let's say if browser width is more than `700px`, then we'll have images on the same row, else, we'll have them one below the other. See the code below for one such implementation.

The HTML can be like this:

```
<div class="container">
  <img src="img/one.jpg">
  <img src="img/two.jpg">
  <img src="img/tri.jpg">
</div>
```

The CSS code will be as below:

```
.container
{
  width:100%;
  text-align:center;
}
.container img
{
  display:inline-block;
  width:200px;
  margin:15px;
}

/*Next block will be followed when browser width is less than 700px*/
@media screen and (max-width:700px)
{
  .container img
  {
    display:block;
    margin:auto;
    width:100%;  /*Use this line only if you want the image to occupy full width*/
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know the width of the image you can add a `@media` query which changes both the `width` of the container and the `flex-direction` from `row` to `column`.

**eg.** Take an `img` which is contained in a `div` - and all the `divs` are collectively contained in a `section`.

If the image has a width of `240px`, and a margin of `20px` (on both sides) and the `div` containing the image has a `2px` border (on both sides) and a `24px` margin (on both sides), then...

a `section` containing three `divs` has a width of:

3 * (`24px` + `2px` + `20px` + `240px` + `20px` + `2px` + `24px`) = `996px`

If you then style the `body` of your document so it has:

```
body {
margin: 12px;
padding: 0;
}
```

you'll know that the point at which the *row of images* has to turn into a *column of images* is when the width of the body is less than `12px` + `996px` + `12px` - or `1020px`.

Then you can set up your `@media` query:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1020px) {

.set {
flex-direction: column;
width: 332px;
}

}
```

**Full example:**

```css
body {
margin: 12px;
padding: 0;
}

.set {
display: flex;
flex-direction: row;
width: 996px;
margin: 0 auto;
background-color: rgb(227,227,227);
}

.set-item, .set-item-image {
display: block;
}

.set-item {
width: 280px;
height: 320px;
margin: 24px;
background-color: rgb(255,255,255);
border: 2px solid rgb(191,191,191);
}

.set-item-image {
width: 240px;
height: 240px;
margin: 20px 20px 8px;
background-color: rgb(191,191,191);
}

.set-item-text {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
text-align: center;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1020px) {

.set {
flex-direction: column;
width: 332px;
}

}
```

```html
<section class="set">
<div class="set-item">
<img class="set-item-image" alt="Image 1" />
<p class="set-item-text">Image 1</p>
</div>

<div class="set-item">
<img class="set-item-image" alt="Image 2" />
<p class="set-item-text">Image 2</p>
</div>

<div class="set-item">
<img class="set-item-image" alt="Image 3" />
<p class="set-item-text">Image 3</p>
</div>
</section>
```